# Проблема с запуском сервера на виртуальной машине

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mongodb

Хотел на vps сервер (beget) залить сайт на mern стеке. На локалхосте все без проблем работает (на разных портах, естественно). Но при попытке залить серверную часть для проверки происходит ошибка с mongodb, как я предполагаю
Возможно проблема с зависимостями, но я новичок, поэтому в этом не особо разбираюсь.

- Версия ubuntu на сервере 20.04
- Версия nodejs на сервере 12.20.9 (из коробки, как я полагаю)
- Версия у меня на машине 18.13.

```
> server@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon main.js

[nodemon] 2.0.21
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
/root/server/mern-blog-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/add_user.js:16
        this.options = options ?? {};
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/server/mern-blog-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Обновите версию node. Скорее всего 12я версия ничего не знает об [операторе нулевого слияния ??](https://learn.javascript.ru/nullish-coalescing-operator)

Comment: Спасибо, с горем пополам обновил через nvm. Не подскажете еще как сделать так, чтобы сервер работал на фоне? А то, когда я закрываю терминал все процессы останавливаются. Про pm2 слышал, но не представляю как с ним работать

Comment: В линуксе можно создать сервис(службу по виндусовому). Однако я в этом слабоват (